# Facebook Page -- Dynamic HTML Based on User

Tags: html, facebook, dynamic, fbml

I'm looking to create a Facebook Page with dynamic content based on the user visiting the page. For example, if the user has "liked" something with the consisting of "soccer" then it would display a little module specifically for soccer... or if they liked "baseball" then it would display baseball.

I guess my overall question is: "What content does FB allow developers to scrape and use in their code?" I want to utilize this on the Static FBML application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean a tab to add to your "Facebook Page"? or a standalone App on Facebook?

Comment: Sorry... yes a tab on facebook using the Static FBML application.

Comment: I suppose you should add this to your question. I don't work with FBML and it's not recommended anyway. So if you **really** need to do this with the Static FBML app, maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks! What would you recommend I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want check the open graph documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Graph API: For accessing profile data
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

In order to request and receive extended information about a profile you need to setup a signed request from the Graph api. This can be done from a custom facebook app.